# Scalable React CSS using 'classnames' with BEM in mind

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

So, React newbie here... I'll start off by saying I have a simple single page application which consists of a few simple pages.

Using react-router I have a 'top-down' set up for my components. To give you a basic idea of my SPA structure see below:

```
index -- layout(react routers) --
                                |--About Page
                                |--Home Page
                                |--Contact Page
```

I am rendering a component called "GlobalHero" from my Home Page component.

**Here is the GlobalHero.jsx component.**

```
import React from "react";
var classNames = require('classnames');
import s from '../../../index.scss';

class GlobalHero extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        //sets initial state
        this.state = {
            fadeIn: "",
            titleSelected: "",
            subTitleSelected: ""
        };
    }

    // <<========= ON COMPONENT RENDER =========
    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log("GlobalHero");
        console.log(this.props);
        this.handleClass("fadeIn");
    }
    // =========>>

    // <<========= CONTROLS THE STATE =========
    handleClass = (param) => {
        if (param === "fadeIn" && this.state.fadeIn != "true") {
            this.setState({fadeIn: "true"});
        }
        if (param === "titleSelected" && this.state.titleSelected != "true") {
            this.setState({titleSelected: "true"});
        }
        if (param === "subTitleSelected" && this.state.subTitleSelected != "true") {
            this.setState({subTitleSelected: "true"});
        }
    }
    // =========>>

    render() {

        const heroImg = require(`../../../images/hero${this.props.page}.jpg`);

        //REMOVES CLASS IN REALTIME BASED ON STATE'S VALUE =========
        var containerClasses = classNames({
            [s['text-center']]: true,
            [s["hidden"]]: this.state.fadeIn != "true",
            [s["fadeIn"]]: this.state.fadeIn === "true"
        });
        var titleClasses = classNames({
            [s['blue']]: this.state.titleSelected === "true"
        });
        var subTitleClasses = classNames({
            [s['subTitle']]: true,
            [s['text-center']]: true,
            [s['blue']]: this.state.subTitleSelected === "true"
        });
        // =========>>

        return (
            <div className={s["container-fluid"]}>
                <div className={s["row"]}>
                    <div className={s["col-lg-16"]}>

                        <div className={containerClasses}>
                            <img src={heroImg} className={s["hero__img"]}></img>
                            <h1 onClick={() => this.handleClass("titleSelected")} className={titleClasses}>{this.props.page}!</h1>
                            <p className={subTitleClasses} onClick={() => this.handleClass("subTitleSelected")}>{this.props.name}, {this.props.age}, {this.props.city}</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default GlobalHero;
```

I noticed there is a lot of complexity there for assigning a few simple class names to the component's elements.

> I was wondering if there is a better practice for doing this? Maybe
>   using an external js page to manage my classnames?

Any input or adivce is appreciated... Thankyou in adnvance.

Comment: can you even import a `.scss` file and have it be interpreted as js? ive never seen that

Comment: Your title says BEM but it looks like you are using CSS Modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title mentions [BEM](http://getbem.com/) but it looks like you are using [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), which is inspired by similar ideas but not the same thing.

Anyway, this is quite subjective but I have a few thoughts that are too much to fit in a comment:

- Assuming you are using css modules through Webpack's `css-loader`, you can use `camelCase` to make your style properties more JS friendly:

  ```
  loader: "css-loader?modules&camelCase"
  ```

  Now for `.text-center` css class name you can simply use `s.textCenter` instead of `s["test-center"]`.
- You could componentize this better: first, you are kind of doing a lot for a single component, but you could [break it down into a few smaller components that each have a single responsibility](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-1-break-the-ui-into-a-component-hierarchy) (for example container, title, subtitle). Second, your `handleClass()` method is doing a lot, when you could just have simple handlers that call `setState()` without knowing anything about class names.  In other words, the component should have props and state, only the `render()` function deals with how to translate that into class names to render. You also really don't need to check the state's current value before setting it. Just set it to what it should be and let React optimize rendering performance for you.
- You have boolean state flags that you store using strings `"true"` and `"false"`... this makes it noisy to handle, just store as booleans.
- You have a lot of `[s["class-name"]]: true` which is not necessary; if you always want a class name to be rendered just pass it as an argument to `classNames`:

  ```
  classNames(s.subTitle, { [s.blue]: this.state.subTitleSelected })
  ```
- There's no reason to call a handler on `componentDidMount`, just initialize the state how you want it.
- It looks like you're using bootstrap CSS but not the [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) components. I would highly recommend using React Bootstrap.

Putting that together I'd have something like:

```
class GlobalHero extends React.Component {

    state = {
        fadeIn: true,
        titleSelected: false,
        subTitleSelected: false
    };

    handleTitleClick = () => {
        this.setState({titleSelected: true});
    };

    handleSubTitleClick = () => {
        this.setState({subTitleSelected: true});
    };

    render() {
        return (
          <Grid fluid>
            <Row>
              <Col lg={16}>
                <HeroContainer fadeIn={this.state.fadeIn}>
                  <HeroImage page={this.props.page} />
                  <HeroTitle selected={this.state.titleSelected} 
                             onClick={this.handleTitleClick} 
                             page={this.props.page} />
                  <HeroSubTitle selected={this.state.subTitleSelected} 
                                onClick={this.handleSubTitleClick} 
                                name={this.props.name} 
                                age={this.props.age} 
                                city={this.props.city} />
                </HeroContainer>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        );
    }
}

const HeroContainer = ({fadeIn, children}) => {
  return (
    <div className={classNames(s.textCenter, fadeIn ? s.fadeIn : s.hidden)}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const HeroImage = ({page}) => {
  const heroImg = require(`../../../images/hero${page}.jpg`);
  return (
    <img src={heroImg} className={s.heroImg} />
  );
};

const HeroTitle = ({onClick, selected, page}) => (
    <h1 onClick={onClick} className={selected ? s.blue : null}>{page}!</h1>
);

const HeroSubTitle = ({onClick, selected, name, age, city}) => (
    <p className={classNames(s.subTitle, s.textCenter, { [s.blue]: selected })} onClick={onClick}>
      {name}, {age}, {city}
    </p>
);
```

Breaking it into smaller components like this is not completely necessary, but notice how from the perspective of `GlobalHero` it does nothing with styles, it just sets props and state, and the little parts have no state, they just render the correct styles based on props.

**PS** maybe this should move to [Code Reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?